# Actionscribpt 3: Move Movieclip from Stage to top from within the Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

im currently trying to convert from AS2 to AS3 and i've got a small problem with depth management. I have several MovieClips on stage called (Window_1, Window_2, ... , Window_N) wich also have several child MovieClips.

The problem is that every Window_X MovieClip is build the same way: 
Window_x -> UI_TopBar -> TopBar_MC. I'm trying to create a universal solution that by clicking on the TopBar_MC the entire Window_X MovieClip gets to the top.

Does anybody know how I could do that?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `stage.addChild(Window_N)`. See documentation: [DisplayObjectContainer.addChild](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29)

> Adds a child DisplayObject instance to this DisplayObjectContainer instance. The child is added to the front (top) of all other children in this DisplayObjectContainer instance.

Comment: You are giving an answer that is correct but set the user on a path to failure (adding anything to stage will result down the road in large headaches and failures). Voted down.

Comment: This is rather an arguable statement. This may or may not cause problems. And if you feel strongly, that it inevitably would, this is still your very own experience and judgement. As the question has it: "I have several MovieClips **on stage** called..." Changing this fact would require quite some work and clarifications, which would be outside the scope of the original question, while failing to give a concise solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

To move a display object to the top of its parent display list:

```
object.parent.setChildIndex(object, object.parent.numChildren - 1);
```

As for how to make this "universal", you can use a class that you link to each window symbol which adds a click handler to the top bar that does the bring-to-front behavior:

```
class Window extends MovieClip {
    public var topBar:MovieClip;
    public function Window() {
        topBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, topBarMouseDown);
    }
    private function topBarMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        parent.setChildIndex(this, parent.numChildren - 1);
    }
}
```